# Could any one give an example of bare "kind"-denoting relative clause?

Tags: definiteness, relative-clauses

There are two kinds of NPs existential and definite. Sometimes NP that we would expect to be existential behave as they are actually definite. One example of such NPs are those that are kind-denoting.

ex:
The snake is a cold blood animal.
The rose is a flower.

These sentences have general meaning and we would expect them to have existential meaning and take indefinite article. However, they take definite article and have definite meaning.

Could any one give examples of relative clauses that have kind-denoting meaning and are definite or is there any articles on this topic?

Thank you.

Comment: _There are two kinds of NPs existential and definite._ Where did this come from, and whose terminology is it? And how is either one different from Generic NPs? Linguistic terminology is not absolute -- you have to provide examples to show the phenomenon you're using the term for. **Not** the other way around.

Comment: *We have two kind of rattlesnakes here: the rattlesnake that breeds in caves, and the one that breeds in sand dunes.* — Or is this not what you meant?

Comment: These are not standard terms; or rather, existential has a meaning, but it refers to quantifiers, and definite has a meaning, but it refers to articles. They are not in contrast, and neither is a definitive categorization for NPs. So it's hard to tell what's involved, especially given the flat law-like character of the first sentence.

Comment: well actually I am not exactly sure about these terms that's why I have asked for examples. Nevertheless, I would try to explain what I am asking in more details. noun phrases are divided into definite and indefinite ones. There are different definitions of what defenetness is that's why I won't try define it. However, there are facts that are generally accepted.

Comment: Definite NPs are presented by definite article the while indefinite ones by indefinite article. as the book in contrast to a book. If I understood correctly existential NPs (or sentences, I don't know how it would be correctly expressed)is a subset of indefinite NPs. These are those that express existence or nonexistence of something and generally begin with There is/ There are.

Comment: They can also be distinguished by strong or weak quantifiers (Milsark, 1974). Strong quantifiers such as all, no, every need presupposition that's why they cannot appear in existential sentences, while week quantifiers such as some and numerals can. One type of sentences which definiteness property can be easily identified is a "kind"-denoting ones. They refer to the group instead of the member. ex: The snake is a cold blooded animal. here snake does not refer to any specific snake but has a meaning of a group of species that are called snakes.

Comment: In the sentence above it is impossible to use indefinite article a, thus the sentence has to have definite meaning.  
I have adopt these properties to distinguish between definite and existential relative clauses. however, I cannot . Think I need some examples or I had misunderstood something. I have no problems with there is/ there are sentences or relative clauses that contain weak or strong quantifiers. however, i am not able to come up with examples where relative clause has "kind" denoting meaning and should be definite.

Comment: I hope that this time I am more specific...

Answer (score 1):

Bare plurals can receive a generic interpretation, in which case they've been argued to denote a kind. A few examples:

Dinosaurs are extinct.
Horses are widespread.

Check out Carlson 1977 "A Unified Analysis of the Bare Plural," reproduced in Portner & Partee's *Formal Semantics*.